# How do I ignore ssl validation in play framework scala ws calls

Tags: web-services, scala, ssl-certificate, playframework-2.1

I want to consume a web service that is using an invalid certificate (self signed)

I want to make the web service call without performing any sort of certificate validation.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your application.conf add the below line

```
ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true
```

Comment: For the last Play version you have to use `play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate = true`

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you going to user play2 as a lib, to allow self-signed ssl certificates you should do the following(2.1.3 as actual version):

- create conf/application.conf with at least one string

  ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true
- create new application

  val app = new play.api.DefaultApplication(new File("."), this.getClass.getClassLoader(), None, play.api.Mode.Dev)
- start new app

  play.api.Play.start(app)
- do ws calls to https resources