# how to ignore Play Framework WS SSL certs without making my entire application insecure?

Tags: scala, ssl, https, playframework-2.0

Newb alert! I'll try to describe this clear and concise.

Scala 2.10.3, Play 2.2.1.

I have a play application that gets used on HTTPS. I have a setting in my `conf/application.conf` file for making sure that my Play app uses SSL (and it's been tested and it's fine):

`session.secure=true`

But now, I want my play app to connect to a webservice, using the WS library. That webservice is on HTTPS with a self-signed SSL certificate. I can set the following setting in my `conf/application.conf` file so that I don't have to deal with the webservice certificates - I'd prefer that. (The webservice is some flavor of special, so I prefer to just not deal with its certificates at all):

`ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true`

When I set both of these to `true` everything appears to compile and run. But dow do these two different settings interact, overlap, and/or interfere? Is it more secure for my app if I use AsyncHttpClient, and set `SSLContext`?

I tried setting up a keymanager and keystore in `conf/application.conf` but my WS call results in an SSLEngine error - I think it is due to me using Play 2.2.1 and the SSL support for WS is only available on Play 2.3.x +

NOTE:
I make the following kind of call using WS. I need the future response to complete, and my function will return a boolean value. Should I instead be using

```
def myfun : Boolean = {
    var ret : Boolean = false
    val futureResult = WS.url("https://somewhere.com").post(jsonInput) onComplete {
       case Success(response) => { 
        ret = true
      }
      case Failure(e) => { 
        Log.error("badness")
      }
    }
    ret
}
```

REF:

[How do I ignore ssl validation in play framework scala ws calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073518/how-do-i-ignore-ssl-validation-in-play-framework-scala-ws-calls)

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/WSQuickStart

Comment: FWIW, `myfun` is always going to return false.

Comment: I anonymized my code before posting it here. it's only purpose is to show the kind of call with WS that I'm making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer only because Will Sargent's answer references Play documentation for a version that does not work in my version of Play (2.3.x vs. 2.2.x)

Solution comes from Will Sargent:

> You should not set ws.acceptAnyCertificate. And you only need a keymanager and a key store if you intend to do client authentication.
>   Add the self signed certificate to your trust store instead, or define a custom trust store on the command line with "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" -- see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization for details.

Answer (score 2):

You should not set ws.acceptAnyCertificate.  And you only need a keymanager and a key store if you intend to do client authentication.

Add the self signed certificate to your trust store instead, or define a custom trust store on the command line with "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" -- see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization for details.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/CertificateGeneration will walk you through how to add a certificate to the truststore.

There is also an activator template that should help: http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-tls-example

Comment: Thanks I'll try defining it on the command line. I don't think you are correct about Play's documentation. I'm using Play 2.2.1 (see my original SO question, above)

Comment: The documentation walks you how to use keytool, not Play.

Comment: The documentation is for Play 2.3.x. Using keytool from the link you posted, does not work for Play 2.2.x. I'll set a system variable with the self-signed trust store as you suggested.